# How to cast hex string as hex integer?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using BLE plugin, which requires to present the values as list of hex number(e.g. `[0x20,0x11,0x06,0x6D]`).

I was able to get a list of hex strings using `int.toRadixString` (`['0x20','0x11','0x06','0x6D']`), but didn't find a way to convert those strings into hex integers.

I'm looking for something like `int demicalToHex(int demical)` or similar function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a hex number. What it needs is a list of integers (`List<int>`).

In the same way that you have `[0x20,0x11,0x06,0x6D]` you could equally write that as `[32, 17, 6, 109]`. Sometimes, it's convenient to think about integers in their decimal representation or their hex representation (or octal, or binary...), but as far as the compiler is concerned, they are just integers.

Just use an array of integers (not strings).

Comment: Ah, thanks. So there will be no difference even for real BLE device if send integers instead of their hex representation?

Comment: As soon as your source code is compiled or interpreted it's turned into binary. It really makes no difference what representation you use in your source code.